# How to do "Searches related to" as in google using java?

Tags: java

I have been working on "Searches related to 'keyword'" as is there in Google but i'm not able to come to any proper idea about how to go about it.

Any help will be highly obliged.

Regards,
Rahul Sharma

Comment: do you mean the spelling mistakes fixer (i.e, query= ibm wotson and google fixes it to IBM Watson) or "you might be also intresetd in... feauture? I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: @amit gr: In google when we search for some keyword, at the bottom of the page it gives "Searches related to **keyword**" this is what i want to do 
Another thing in Rediff when we search for a particular keyword, at the bottom of the page we get "Also try:"

Comment: then I think what @WhiteFang suggested (using Lucene) would be ideal. You can also try doing Link Analyzis (if a user queries A, and then queries B, A is probably related to B...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) contribution called [MoreLikeThis](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/similar/MoreLikeThis.html) that does what I believe you're looking for. You might want to read this article: [Using Lucene and MoreLikeThis to show Related Content](http://cephas.net/blog/2006/11/14/using-lucene-and-morelikethis-to-show-related-content/).

Comment: i would request you to go to [link](http://www.rediff.com) and make a search for suppose say "Cat" at the end of the page it gives "Also try" which has terms related to Cat as well as some other links 
hope you can help me out in getting this one

Answer (score 0):

The query refinements subsection of Google's [features](http://www.google.com/help/features.html) page may be helpful.

In your case you could hit the URL http://www.google.com/search?q=related:<related_url>+<query>